# Can't implement treeview with mutually exclusive checkboxes

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, checkbox, treeview

I need to implement a treeview with following behavior:

When user checks an item, previously checked items get unchecked. I am not native English speaker but I understand this behavior is called *mutually exclusive checkboxes*.

I have found [`TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES` extended style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759981(v=vs.85).aspx) that seemed to suit my needs but I can not use it successfully.

I am setting `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style properly by using `SetWindowLongPtr` instead of simply passing it to `CreateWindowEx` as MSDN recommended. I then use `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr` to add the extended style I mentioned above. The code compiles but runs as if I have never added the extended style.

- I have linked commctrl library and enabled visual styles;
- I have initialized common controls;

Below is the `WM_CREATE` handler.

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    HWND hwndTV = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, L"tv", 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | 
        TVS_FULLROWSELECT | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT,
        50, 50, 150, 250, hWnd, (HMENU)4000, hInst, 0);

    // add checkbox

    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwndTV, GWL_STYLE), 
        dwExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwndTV, GWL_EXSTYLE);

    dwStyle |= TVS_CHECKBOXES;
    dwExStyle |= TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES;
    
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwndTV, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwndTV, GWL_EXSTYLE, dwExStyle);

    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = { 0 };
    
    tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
    tvis.item.pszText = L"ROOT ITEM 1";
    HTREEITEM root1 = TreeView_InsertItem(hwndTV, &tvis);

    tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
    tvis.item.pszText = L"ROOT ITEM 2";
    HTREEITEM root2 = TreeView_InsertItem(hwndTV, &tvis);

    tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
    tvis.item.pszText = L"First child";
    tvis.hParent = root1;
    tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_FIRST;
    HTREEITEM child1 = TreeView_InsertItem(hwndTV, &tvis);
}
```

### QUESTIONS:

Have I misunderstood the docs for `TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES`?

- If not, then how should my code be modified to behave the way I described earlier?
- If yes, then please tell me so.

Comment: For the future reader: you must call TreeView_SetExtendedStyle **BEFORE** you set `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style!

Comment: So does `TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES` actually do what you were hoping it would?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: No it doesn't. I guess the only way is the one you recommended me before...

Comment: Raymond Chen explains how this style works: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171205-00/?p=97525
And this style is not what OP wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TVS_EX_xxx` styles aren't "extended window styles", they're "extended treeview styles". They can only be set using the [`TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

```
TreeView_SetExtendedStyle(hwndTV,
           TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES, TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Mr. Potter. I have copy/pasted your code and still do not get the behavior I need. I have checked the return code for `TreeView_SetExtendedStyle` and it reports no error. Should I edit my post with the reworked code or will you tackle this on your own for a start?

Comment: I suspect `TVS_EX_EXCLUSIONCHECKBOXES` doesn't do what you think it does. I don't actually know what it does; I've never used it and it doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: Indeed all those new styles are poorly documented.  have tried to change that style with the one for partial checkboxes but it failed too. I will upvote your answer but will wait for a while to see if someone else will shed some light. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: I mean it would not be hard to code this yourself. If you only want one checkbox selected at once, just keep a track of the "checked" item, and when a new item is checked, uncheck the old one.

Comment: Yes, I did that earlier by introducing `static` variable. I just wanted to try out this style so I can remove the `static` variable...

Comment: Fair enough. Well, maybe Raymond Chen will wander past and deign to share some of his knowledge with us... :)

Comment: Mr.Potter, I have decided to award you the bounty because I doubt anyone else will provide the alternative solution. Although your answer doesn't solve my problem, I appreciate your good will to read my question, and your intent to try to solve it. Best regards and happy New Year.